# Display a checkbox using Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have declared bool property like so;

```
public bool ApplyingMyself { get; set; }
```

I have the following mark-up for the checkbox

```
@Html.Label("I am a young person applying for myself")
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ApplyingMyself)
```

But receiving error

> Model' does not contain a definition for 'ApplyingMyself' and no
>   extension method 'ApplyingMyself' accepting a first argument of type
>   'Model' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

Any help much appreciated...

Comment: Have you used the same model for the view for this `ApplyingMyself` property is added?

Comment: No, misspelled my class name, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Some additional context may be required to answer your question but the following may address your issue.

Ensure that you've declared the model you're implementing in your View:

```
//At the top of your view:
@model ModelName


// the code for your checkbox in your view
@Html.Label("I am a young person applying for myself")
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ApplyingMyself)
```

If this is already the case and you have your model declared in your view, it is possible that you've updated your model with the ApplyingMyself property and Visual Studio is "unaware" of the change.

1. Try rebuilding your project (in VS 2017 you can select Build -> Rebuild). This will clear your projects binaries and rebuild them from scratch.
2. Try restarting Visual Studio.